# Checkout personalizado en VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, .net

Necesitaría ayuda para integrar personalizado. Estoy trabajando en Visual Studio 2010. Me da el siguiente error cuando quiero realizar `init_point`

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: url
```

Adjunto el código. Si paso variables `p00` y `p01` no me genera el error.

```
Dim ok As String = ""
Dim fail As String = ""
Dim pending As String = ""
Dim _img As String = "http://www.xx.com.ar/images/products/" + Trim(_id) + ".jpg"
Dim url As String = ""
Dim p00 As String = "{""items"":[{""id"":" & Chr(34) + Trim(_id) + Chr(34) & ",""title"":" & Chr(34) + Trim(_des) + Chr(34) & ",""description"":" & Chr(34) + Trim(_des) + Chr(34) & ",""picture_url"":" & Chr(34) + _img + Chr(34) & ",""quantity"":" & _can & ",""currency_id"":""ARS"",""unit_price"":" & Session("importe") & "}]"
Dim p01 As String = """payer"":[{""name"":" & Chr(34) + TxtNombre.Text + Chr(34) & ",""surname"":" & Chr(34) + TxtApellido.Text + Chr(34) & ",""email"":" & Chr(34) + TxtEmail.Text + Chr(34) & "}]"
Dim p02 As String = """back_urls"":[{""success"":" & Chr(34) + ok + Chr(34) & ",""pending"":" & Chr(34) + pending + Chr(34) & ",""failure"":" & Chr(34) + fail + Chr(34) & "}]"
Dim p03 As String = """auto_return"":[{""approved""}]"
Dim p04 As String = """notification_url"":[{" & Chr(34) + url + Chr(34) & "}]"
Dim prefe As String = p00 + "," + p01 + "," + p02 + "," + p03 + "," + p04 + "}"
Dim preference1 As Hashtable = mp.createPreference(prefe)
Response.Redirect(preference1("response")("init_point"))
```

Comment: ¿Podrías colocar el código de `.createPreference`?

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Dim preference1 As Hashtable = mp.createPreference(prefe)
        Response.Redirect(preference1("response")("init_point"))

Comment: disculpa la demora carlos